# How to pull new branch from A to by fork B?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo A to my repo B.

Repo A created a new branch.

How do I pull the new branch from A to my repo B?

Comment: Both [github](http://github.com/) and [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/) have *pull requests*, and [git](http://git-scm.com/) has an *excellent* documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you have two remotes. One is your origin (your fork) and other is original canonical repo (upstream).

Let assume `upstream` is the name of remote and and `new-branch` is the name branch from canonical forked repo. (you should check the names)

```sh
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/new-branch
```

Above command might leave you in detached HEAD state, as you are not in any local branch at this moment. You may create a local branch :

```sh
git branch local-new-branch
```

To do it at once :

```sh
git checkout -b local-new-branch upstream/new-branch
```

You may check your remotes with :

```sh
git remote -v
```

If you haven't add the remote yet :

```sh
git remote add upstream https://github.com/bla-bla/bla-bla.git
```

Comment: `upstream` is my remote or the original remote? So, I need first to add the original git project as a remote to my project, right?

Comment: upstream is the original remote (not your origin). yes, you need to add it to your local remotes.

Comment: i have updated  to answer for the command to add remote. let me know if answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

To get all branches of a remote, run `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin` to fetch only from your remote named `origin`).

If you want to only fetch a single branch, provide a refspec:

```
git fetch origin branch:branch
```

(all commands have to be run in your repository).